Problem after running Software Updater on Ubuntu 22.04 - blinking prohibit icon at the bottom of the desktop due to headphones
After running Software Updater on Ubuntu 22.04 I have a blinking prohibit icon at the bottom of my desktop. The keyboard works fine. After several attempts, I found out that the problem is the headphones. As soon as I have unplugged the jack the prohibit icon disappeared. As soon as I have plugged the jack back in, the icon magically reappeared. I tried changing the headphones but the problem persists. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Summary of updates before the problem appeared:
Start-Date: 2024-08-13  20:53:51
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.112'
Install: linux-tools-common:amd64 (5.15.0-118.128, automatic), linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), hwdata:amd64 (0.357-1, automatic), linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3)
End-Date: 2024-08-13  20:54:29

Start-Date: 2024-08-13  20:57:39
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.110'
Remove: linux-modules-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-headers-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-44:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-08-13  20:57:56

2024-08-13 20:54:08 status installed linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:08 status installed hwdata:all 0.357-1
2024-08-13 20:54:08 status installed linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40:all 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:08 status installed linux-tools-common:all 5.15.0-118.128
2024-08-13 20:54:08 status installed linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:10 status installed linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:12 status installed linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:12 status installed linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:12 status installed linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:12 status installed linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:12 status installed linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:12 status installed linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:54:13 status installed man-db:amd64 2.10.2-1
2024-08-13 20:54:29 status installed linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3
2024-08-13 20:57:39 status installed linux-headers-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1
2024-08-13 20:57:40 status installed linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-44:all 6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1
2024-08-13 20:57:45 status installed linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1
2024-08-13 20:57:49 status installed linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1
2024-08-13 20:57:55 status installed linux-modules-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1
2024-08-13 21:21:10 status installed ubuntu-minimal:amd64 1.481.3
2024-08-13 21:21:11 status installed ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1.481.3
2024-08-13 21:21:11 status installed ubuntu-standard:amd64 1.481.3
2024-08-13 21:21:11 status installed ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.481.3

I also noticed that after the problem appeared, everytime I log out, I have a black screen with several ^@ symbols
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@


Please edit the question and add some details. Upgraded what to what ? What commands or steps did you use? Were there any errors and or messages during the upgrade? Also anything else you have not included.

I just run Software Updater. No errors. At the end of operations I reboot. After reboot I had the blinking icon as shown in the image I shared

I still do not see a version of Ubuntu mentioned in all that.

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

The icon means "unrecognized input". Check your keyboard for a stuck key.

I have unplugged the keyboard for over 5 minutes but the icon continues to flash
